# ElasticSearch Aggs Query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a following elasticsearch query and result. I want something like group by with count(*) =1 in sql statement

```
{
"size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_RequestID": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "RequestID"
      } 
    }
  }
}


{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 12,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "group_by_RequestID": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "20160209 132857.249_5420_1_ATL",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "20160209 132857.249_5420_1_DEN1100",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "20160209 132857.249_5420_1_LAS",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "20160209 132857.249_5420_1_PHX1300",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "20160209 132857.249_5420_1_PHX1400",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "20160209 132857.249_5420_1_SFO",
          "doc_count": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I want my result to be back where "doc_count" = 1 
 can you guide me how can i get that result ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should get desired results [Bucket selector aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html) with use of a [special](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline.html#_special_paths) `_count` field